# Failed to find data adapter that can handle input:...(list to numpy array with given dimensions)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a list X in python which contains 20000 images of dimension (100,100,3) each. Each of the images is of type numpy.ndarray. I wish to input this list of images as the training vector for a CNN model using model.fit(X) in Tensorflow. However doing so gives me the following error:

`ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'numpy.ndarray'>"}), (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'numpy.int64'>"})`

Would converting list X into a numpy.ndarray of dimensions (20000,100,100,3) help?

If yes, how can I do that?

If not, could you please suggest what can be done?

Comment: What does `np.array(X)` produce?  Especially what's the `shape` and `dtype`?  Beware of 1d array with object dtype - the means the list contains arrays that differ in shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you give a list of np.array as input to fit() method, is considered as your model has multiple inputs.Yes, you have to create a np.array  or tf.tensor from the listX.
It is a good thing to convert your data to tf.data.dataset :

```
data_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(  (your_converted_listX ,your_converted_listY) )
model.fit(data_set)
```

if the data is too large ,consider using tf.data.Dataset.from_generator instead.